# Acessing WordPress locally on different network

Tags: wordpress

I've been having trouble accessing my local wordpress project on different network. The site just keeps loading, and I can't even access the admin panel. I inspected the net panel. It's showing this IP instead of 'localhost' or my real local IP. Since I'm new to wordpress I would like to hear some solutions to this problem.

EDIT: The problem was in the Database. That IP was stored in options table.
I used [interconnectit](https://interconnectit.com/) to change the '192.168.0.12' to 'localhost' and I can confirm that it works now.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To run wordpress on your local pc you should have a server installed, for example [wamp server](http://wampserver.com/).

If this step is fine, make sure that you are masking correctly localhost with this ip at hosts file (C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc).

Finally, if you are moving wordpress from another location, make sure that all db records (especially on wp_options table) have the url changed.

Comment: Hmmm... In that case, it might be a problem with the port maybe. Maybe the router is using it for something else and you have a conflict there.

Answer (score -1):

For sharing project hosted localhost over network, you can use [Ngrok](https://ngrok.com/)

Comment: Just providing a framework/library will not solve the OPs issue.